# what is the reason user cannot enter input after the 2nd question and compiler finish the program?

Tags: c++, input

I'd like to write a program that asks the user if he/she tends to work as a delivery service. If yes he/she should have some eligibilities. If the user have them he/she can be hired.

I've written some code, but when I compile and run it, after the user answered 2 first questions the `cmd` doesn't let the user to enter his/her answers for remaining questions (the `cin` code doesn't work anymore or as though there is no `cin` code.)

What's wrong with my code? Why `cin` doesn't work after 2 first question but it works at first 2 ones? How can I make it work?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string answer{}, ssn1{}, a, b;
    int age{0};
    bool parental_consent{false}, ssn{false}, accidents{false};
    cout << boolalpha;

    cout << "Do you want to work as a local delivery (Y/N)? \n";
    cin >> answer;
    if (answer == "Y" || answer == "y")
    {
        cout << "Do you have any social security number(yes/no)? \n";
        cin >> ssn;
        ssn = ("yes" || "Yes");

        cout << "How old are you? \n";
        cin >> a;
        cout << age;
        cout << "If you're between 15 and 18 years old please answer this question: \n Do have parental "
                "consent(yes/no)? \n";
        cin >> ssn1;
        //  cout << parental_consent;
        parental_consent = ("yes" || "Yes");
        cout << "Have you ever had any accidents? \n";
        cin >> b;
        accidents = ("yes" || "Yes");

        if ((age >= 18 || (age >= 16 && parental_consent)) && ssn && !accidents)
        {

            cout << "Yes, you can work.";
        }
        else if (age <= 15)
        {
            cout << "Sorry, your age is not eligble!\n";
        }
    }
    else
        cout << "sorry to hear that.";

    cout << endl << endl << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cin >> ssn; ssn = ("yes" || "Yes");` What is this supposed to do? And please include input, output and expected output in the question

Comment: This is wrong: `"Do you have any social security number(yes/no)? \n"` since you are reading `bool` not `string` value for this question, so accepting input is `true`/`false` or `1`/`0`.

Comment: also your code assumes magical transfer of values between variables. For example you are reading age into `a` and then you are expecting that it is inside `age` which has different type.

Comment: `ssn = ("yes" || "Yes");` string literal is considered "true", so this line is basically `ssn = true;`

Answer (score 0):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get):

> If the type of v is bool and boolalpha is not set, then if the value to be stored is ​0​, false is stored, if the value to be stored is 1, true is stored, for any other value std::ios_base::failbit is assigned to err and true is stored.

From the code, i can see that the second `std::cin` doesn't have boolalpha and is assigning to a bool value. This causes td::ios_base::failbit to be assigned to err, preventing other input. You have to do `std::cin.clear();` to be able to use `std::cin >> a;` again.

**If it still skips**
Try using `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` after every `std::cin` to clear out whitespaces that causes it to return immediately.

**It seems you wanted to use** `std::boolalpha` to convert your questions into boolean. This obviously didn't work because you used it on `std::cout` to use it on input you need to use it on `std::cin` like this:

```cpp
cin >> boolalpha >> ssn;
```

But you can't answer `yes` or `Yes`, you need to answer `true` or `false` so it's better to just `std::cin >> answer` and compare the string instead like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    std::string answer{};
    int age{ 0 };
    bool parental_consent{ false }, ssn{ false }, accidents{ false };


    std::cout << "Do you want to work as a local delivery (Y/N)? \n";
    std::cin >> answer;
    if (answer == "Y" || answer == "y")
    {
        std::cout << "Do you have any social security number(yes/no)? \n";
        std::cin >> answer;
        ssn = (answer == "yes" || answer == "Yes");

        std::cout << "How old are you? \n";
        std::cin >> answer;
        age = atoi(answer.c_str());
        if (age >= 15 && age <= 18) {
            std::cout << "If you're between 15 and 18 years old please answer this question: \n Do have parental "
                "consent(yes/no)? \n";
            std::cin >> answer;
            parental_consent = (answer == "yes" || answer == "Yes");
        }
        std::cout << "Have you ever had any accidents? \n";
        std::cin >> answer;
        accidents = (answer == "yes" || answer == "Yes");

        if ((age >= 18 || (age >= 16 && parental_consent)) && ssn && !accidents)
        {

            std::cout << "Yes, you can work.";
        }
        else if (age <= 15)
        {
            std::cout << "Sorry, your age is not eligble!\n";
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "sorry to hear that.";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```cpp
cin>>answer;
if(answer=="yes"||"Yes"== answer)
ssn=true;



This line will only make the left of the = being true:
ssn = ("yes" || "Yes");
```

Comment: doesn't look like an answer and doesn't seems that you understand what problem he has.

Comment: Now I understand so this is wrong to use `bool` as string best thing I can do to change the variable to sting and rewrite the code again and check them with `bool` if they are true or false. or I can change the type of strings to bool with `static_cast<bool>`. right?

Comment: One thing is that if a bool not equal(=) to 0 it will always be true.